# add listView and imageView at its end

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to create the layout to be like what in the diagram

[image]

how can I make the listView Scroll independently and make the textView and ImageView stead?

Comment: not sure what do you want. ListViews scrolls independently by default, so just putting them weights or fixed size will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace your xml layout like below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/yourimg" />

</LinearLayout>
```

above xml given output below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> For the Lower Steady Image View you can use : Create a footer view
>   layout consisting of text that you want to set as footer and then try

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
ListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

> For Header: The solution that works for me is to create a TableLayout
>   that has a row with the heading and a row with the list like this:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <include layout="@layout/header" />

   <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   />

</TableLayout>
Please make sure that the ListView has @android:id/list as the ID.
```

> OR
>
> Rather google adding header and footer to listview in android that
>   will help u much better

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the pseudo code, I can try a better attempt later on, but you need:

```
RelativeLayout
    TextView - align top
    ImageView - align bottom
    ScrollView - align above ImageView, align below TextView
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a linear layout with orientation as vertical. Add textview listview and imageview with the weight as you want. Remember to give layout_height as 0dp for all the three components.

Answer (score 0):

Add Header And Footer To the Listview,Like

ListView mList=getListView();
mList.addHeaderView(View v);//Your textView
 and
mList.addFooterView(v);//your imageview

Comment: your answer great too but it leads to make the image scrolls with the list.